# Convert a list of float to string in Python

Tags: python, list, formatting, precision, floating-point-conversion

I have a list of floats in Python and when I convert it into a string, I get the following

```py
[1883.95, 1878.3299999999999, 1869.4300000000001, 1863.4000000000001]
```

These floats have 2 digits after the decimal point when I created them (I believe so),

Then I used

```py
str(mylist)
```

How do I get a string with 2 digits after the decimal point?

======================

Let me be more specific, I want the end result to be a string and I want to keep the separators:

```py
"[1883.95, 1878.33, 1869.43, 1863.40]"
```

I need to do some string operations afterwards. For example `+="!\t!"`.

Inspired by @senshin the following code works for example, but I think there is a better way

```py
msg = "["

for x in mylist:
    msg += '{:.2f}'.format(x)+','

msg = msg[0:len(msg)-1]
msg+="]"
print msg
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use string formatting to get the desired number of decimal places.

```
>>> nums = [1883.95, 1878.3299999999999, 1869.4300000000001, 1863.4000000000001]
>>> ['{:.2f}'.format(x) for x in nums]
['1883.95', '1878.33', '1869.43', '1863.40']
```

The format string `{:.2f}` means "print a fixed-point number (`f`) with two places after the decimal point (`.2`)". `str.format` will automatically round the number correctly (assuming you entered the numbers with two decimal places in the first place, in which case the floating-point error won't be enough to mess with the rounding).

Comment: That works, I got ['1883.95', '1878.33', '1869.43', '1863.40']
however, can I get something like "[1883.95, 1878.33, 1869.43, 1863.40]"? I need to some string operation afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: @Niebieski You want a string representation of the whole list? I very much doubt that that's what you _actually_ want, but you can just call `str()` on the list to get something close.

Comment: I want to do += "!\t!", or similar operation

Comment: @Niebieski But _why_ do you want to do that? Why wouldn't you just perform string operations on the individual numbers?

Comment: I am generating an email summary of this list, so I need the end result to be a string and I want to keep the separators. I am looking for an elegant way to do so. I thought str(mylist) would do it but it gives that annoying additional digits

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep full precision, the syntactically simplest/clearest way seems to be

```
mylist = list(map(str, mylist))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
map(lambda n: '%.2f'%n, [1883.95, 1878.3299999999999, 1869.4300000000001, 1863.4000000000001])
```

`map()` invokes the callable passed in the first argument for each element in the list/iterable passed as the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the ' marks:

```
>>> nums = [1883.95, 1878.3299999999999, 1869.4300000000001, 1863.4000000000001]
>>> '[{:s}]'.format(', '.join(['{:.2f}'.format(x) for x in nums]))
'[1883.95, 1878.33, 1869.43, 1863.40]'
```

- **['{:.2f}'.format(x) for x in nums]** makes a list of strings, as in the accepted answer.
- **', '.join([list])** returns one string with ', ' inserted between the list elements.
- **'[{:s}]'.format(joined_string)** adds the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
str([round(i, 2) for i in mylist])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy you may do:

`np.array2string(np.asarray(mylist), precision=2, separator=', ')`